# Get data from url with thread in X time

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In objective c ,i need get data from url in background (thread) with a period time.

¿ ideas ?

nsthread
dispatch
performSelectorInBackground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GCD's `dispatch_after()`

```
// Delay execution of my block for 2 seconds.
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    // Do whatever you want in the background here.
});
```